# Find and replace text iteratively from a list

Tags: java, python, regex, perl, notepad++

Suppose I have these text :

```
Donec sollicitudin ? malesuada. "Curabitur" arcu erat, accumsan
id imperdiet et, porttitor at sem. Quisque velit nisi, ? ut
lacinia in, ? id enim. Proin eget tortor risus.
```

and I have these texts in list :

```
["apple", "banana", "cherry"]
```

How can I replace each occurence of ? with each of the text in the list ? Expected output :

```
Donec sollicitudin apple malesuada. "Curabitur" arcu erat, accumsan
id imperdiet et, porttitor at sem. Quisque velit nisi, banana ut
lacinia in, cherry id enim. Proin eget tortor risus.
```

Is it possible to use notepad++ to achieve something like this for a longer text and list? Or is there any other technologies that I can use ?

Comment: You can write a script or write a simple program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Python script will get the job done. If there are more `?` than replacements in the list, it will leave them as `?`.

```
import re

replacements = ["apple", "banana", "cherry"]
lines = ""

with open("file.txt") as file:
    lines = file.read()

def replace(m):
    if not replacements:
        return "?"

    return replacements.pop(0)

lines = re.sub(r"\?", replace, lines)

with open("file.txt", "w") as file:
    file.write(lines)
```

Admittedly, there are better ways of doing this, such as not loading the entire file into a string.

Comment: thanks, it's working.. I try to avoid scripting but it's ok

Answer (score 0):

You could try doing three regex replacements in succession:

**Find:**

```
([^?]*)?\?(.*)
```

**Replace:**

```
$1apple$2
```

The trick here is that `([^?]*)?\?` matches everything up until the *first* question mark.  This allows us to do a controlled replacement of only one `?` placeholder at a time.

You would then repeat the above the above replacement from left to right for the other two keywords.

Comment: thanks but the text is just a sample.. I may have hundreds of replacement, just scared of mistake if I replace one by one.. I'll do this if nothing else works..

Comment: @Mrye Then you may need to write a  script in a language like Java or Perl to handle this.  Notepad++ can only do so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below regex:

```
\?(?!(.|\s)*\?(.|\s)*)
```

It will pick the **last** `?` and provide you the index of it. After that you can replace it with the last element of your array (it would be better if you create a stack which contains `["apple", "banana", "cherry"]` so that `stack.pop` method will always give you the last element.)

Answer (score 0):

In Perl:

```
$text =~ s{\?}{shift @fruits}eg;  # Consumes @fruits array
```

Or

```
my $i = 0;
$text =~ s{\?}{$fruits[$i++]}g;   # Preserves @fruits
```

To cycle over `@fruits` (if the number of `?`s exceeds the number of fruits):

```
my $i = 0;
$text =~ s{\?}{$fruits[ $i++ % @fruits ]}g;
```